# convert bytes to ascii if possible, hex otherwise

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8

Imagine you have this byte array:

```
 b = bytes([0x00, 0x78, 0x6f, 0x58, 0x00, 0x4f, 0x30, 0x00]
```

and you want to print it in a somewhat readable way, using ASCII when possible and hex when not.  You could simply use Python's built-in conversion:

```
>>> b
b'\x00xoX\x00O0\x00'
```

But that's really not particularly readable.  What I'd like is this:

```
00  x  o  X 00  O  0 00
```

...that is, a space and the ASCII char if the byte can be printed as ASCII or a two-digit hex value otherwise.  I can think of some really awful ways to code this, but there must be a semi-elegant pythonic way.  (An array of strings would be great, since you could join() them with a leading space as I've shown above.)  How would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings have [`isprintable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isprintable) and [`isascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isascii) methods which you can use:

```
>>> def int2str(i):
...     s = chr(i)
...     if s.isprintable() and s.isascii():
...         return format(s, ">2s")
...     return format(i, "02x")
... 
>>> print(' '.join(map(int2str, b)))
00  x  o  X 00  O  0 00
>>> print(*map(int2str, b))
00  x  o  X 00  O  0 00
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a couple ways that handle longer `bytes` objects as well:

```py
op = bytes([0x00, 0x78, 0x6f, 0x58, 0x00, 0x4f, 0x30, 0x00])
b = bytes(range(256))

def hexdump(b, bytes_per_line=16):
    for i in range(0, len(b), bytes_per_line):
        chunk = b[i:i+bytes_per_line]
        h = chunk.hex(' ')
        a = ''.join([chr(x) if 0x1f < x < 0x7f else '.' for x in chunk])
        print(f'{h:{bytes_per_line*3}}{a}')

def mixdump(b, bytes_per_line=16):
    for i in range(0, len(b), bytes_per_line):
        chunk = b[i:i+bytes_per_line]
        a = ' '.join([f'{chr(x):>2}' if 0x1f < x < 0x7f else f'{x:02x}' for x in chunk])
        print(a)

hexdump(op)
print()
mixdump(op)
print()
hexdump(b)
print()
mixdump(b)
```

Output:

```
00 78 6f 58 00 4f 30 00                         .xoX.O0.

00  x  o  X 00  O  0 00

00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f ................
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f ................
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f  !"#$%&'()*+,-./
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f 0123456789:;<=>?
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f @ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e 5f PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f `abcdefghijklmno
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 7b 7c 7d 7e 7f pqrstuvwxyz{|}~.
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8a 8b 8c 8d 8e 8f ................
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 9a 9b 9c 9d 9e 9f ................
a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 aa ab ac ad ae af ................
b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9 ba bb bc bd be bf ................
c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 ca cb cc cd ce cf ................
d0 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9 da db dc dd de df ................
e0 e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8 e9 ea eb ec ed ee ef ................
f0 f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 fa fb fc fd fe ff ................

00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f
    !  "  #  $  %  &  '  (  )  *  +  ,  -  .  /
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  :  ;  <  =  >  ?
 @  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O
 P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z  [  \  ]  ^  _
 `  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o
 p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z  {  |  }  ~ 7f
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8a 8b 8c 8d 8e 8f
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 9a 9b 9c 9d 9e 9f
a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 aa ab ac ad ae af
b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9 ba bb bc bd be bf
c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 ca cb cc cd ce cf
d0 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9 da db dc dd de df
e0 e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8 e9 ea eb ec ed ee ef
f0 f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 fa fb fc fd fe ff
```

Comment: Heh - I've written the equivalent of `hexdump` dozens of times for different projects.  Both of your functions (hextump and mixdump) are great tools for future use -- thanks.